Gitlab Self-Hosted: ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "archive" - only for the built Docker image
I am using self-hosted GitLab trying to build a Docker image from my application project with the GitLab runner. The build process completes successfully. The problem occurs when I try to upload the built image as an artifact. The file is around 1.5 GB in size. Other files upload correctly as artifacts.
I get:

ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 413 Request Entity Too Large id=12966 responseStatus=413 Request Entity Too Large status=413 token=glcbt-64
FATAL: too large

I increased the allowed artifact size both in GitLab and Nginx up to 2 GB.
I tried the following:

Uploading a different generated file as an artifact that was almost 2 GB – the operation completed successfully.
Splitting the Docker image into smaller parts (down to 10 MB) – I still couldn't upload them as artifacts.
Uploading a file from the code repository as an artifact, which was over 100 MB – the operation completed successfully.
Compressing the Docker image with bzip2, reducing its size to around 500 MB – I still couldn't upload it.
I ran the GitLab Runner service as root.

I’m not sure why I’m having trouble uploading the saved Docker image as an artifact, but it’s the only one I really need.
My gitlab-ci.yml file:
stages:
  - build
build_image:
  stage: build
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375 
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      alias: docker
      command: ["--tls=false"]
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - echo "Building Docker image with tag tag1"
    - docker build -t app_test:tag1 .
    - mkdir image
    - docker save app_test:tag1 -o image/app_tag1.tar
    # - chmod 777 image -R
    - ls -lh image/

    - docker rmi app_test:tag1  # Remove the built image
    - docker system prune -af  # Remove all unused images and cache
     
    # - echo "Compressing the tar file to bz2"
    # - bzip2 app_tag1.tar
    # - echo "Docker image saved and compressed as app_tag1.tar.bz2"
    
    
    # - echo "Splitting the file into parts"
    # - split -b 9371840 image/app_tag1.tar.bz2 image/app_tag1_part_
    # - ls -lh
    
    # Generate a test file
    # - dd if=/dev/zero of=image/test.bin bs=1M count=1950

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - image
    expire_in: 2 day    


but why use an artifacts and not docker storage?

I need a package with the Docker image to send to a machine that is offline and not connected to a Docker registry.

sorry, more specific, why not use gitlab docker registry? If it's connected to gitlab, then use gitlab. If it's connected to gitlab, and you are using artifacts, you imght be using gitlab docker registry. As for your issue FATAL: too large check your gitlab server configuration, it is responding with too large.
